# Cassandra Server Crashes when we try to retrieve Large data

Tags: java, cassandra

How to retrieve the large data using cassandra DB. I am  using cassandra 1.1.7. with 32 GB RAM and 1 TB hard disk. Successfully, I can insert the record in to it. While I am trying to retrieve the data

Eg:

```
select * from table name (or) select count(*) from tablename;
```

Cassandra server may crashed or shutdown (Table contains 300k rows with 10 columns).

It shows error:

> Adjust the flush_largest_memtables_at_threshold size in yaml or clear cache size

And JVM heap-dump error it created the `pid-XXX.hprof` files in `cassandra/bin` folder.

In `cassandra-env.sh`, I set:

```
MAX_HEAP_SIZE="27G" HEAP_NEWSIZE="2G"
```

In `cassandra.yaml` I have set:

```
memtable_total_space_in_mb: 100
```

Day by day we are inserting 100k above data per table so the cassandra data size may increased 1G per day. So whether I need to increase My RAM size along with it?

Answer (score 3):

Two things here:

1) Your `MAX_HEAP_SIZE` is way too big.  [DataStax's documentation on Java heap tuning](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_tune_jvm_c.html) provides a table to help you determine the correct setting based-on your system RAM.  For 32GB of RAM you would fall into the "Greater than 4GB" category.  The recommended value is then:

> 1/4 system memory, but not more than 8GB

The reason is further down...

> In most cases, the capability of Java to gracefully handle garbage collection above 8GB quickly diminishes.

Seriously consider dropping that down to 8GB or less for `MAX_HEAP_SZIE`.  For `HEAP_NEWSIZE` it is recommended to set that to 100MB per core.  If commented-out, `HEAP_NEWSIZE` will be 1/4 of your `MAX_HEAP_SIZE`.

Better yet, comment-out *both* your settings for `MAX_HEAP_SIZE` and `HEAP_NEWSIZE` in `cassandra-env.sh`.  This way, Cassandra will determine what it needs for those values.  And considering how wildly off-the-mark your current settings are, letting Cassandra determine those for you is the better option.

2) Your `memtable_total_space_in_mb` is also drastically out-of-whack.  I would also comment-out this setting.  Cassandra will set this to 1/3 of heap space by default, meaning that this setting is directly related to the previous settings that are also incorrect.

By commenting-out those settings and allowing Cassandra to manage them, your values should come out like this:

```
MAX_HEAP_SIZE: 8192M
HEAP_NEWSIZE: (num cores) x 100M, or (1/4 of MAX)...2048M
memtable_total_space_in_mb: 2731
```

For help is figuring all this out, I have created a bash script based-on the code in `cassandra-env.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "This is how Cassandra will determine its default Heap and GC Generation sizes."

system_memory_in_mb=`free -m | awk '/Mem:/ {print $2}'`
half_system_memory_in_mb=`expr $system_memory_in_mb / 2`
quarter_system_memory_in_mb=`expr $half_system_memory_in_mb / 2`

echo "   memory = $system_memory_in_mb"
echo "     half = $half_system_memory_in_mb"
echo "  quarter = $quarter_system_memory_in_mb"

echo "cpu cores = "`egrep -c 'processor([[:space:]]+):.*' /proc/cpuinfo`

#cassandra-env logic duped here
#this should help you to see how much memory is being allocated
#to the JVM
    if [ "$half_system_memory_in_mb" -gt "1024" ]
    then
        half_system_memory_in_mb="1024"
    fi
    if [ "$quarter_system_memory_in_mb" -gt "8192" ]
    then
        quarter_system_memory_in_mb="8192"
    fi
    if [ "$half_system_memory_in_mb" -gt "$quarter_system_memory_in_mb" ]
    then
        max_heap_size_in_mb="$half_system_memory_in_mb"
    else
        max_heap_size_in_mb="$quarter_system_memory_in_mb"
    fi
    MAX_HEAP_SIZE="${max_heap_size_in_mb}M"

    # Young gen: min(max_sensible_per_modern_cpu_core * num_cores, 1/4 * heap size)
    max_sensible_yg_per_core_in_mb="100"
#doesn't work?
#    max_sensible_yg_in_mb=`expr (max_sensible_yg_per_core_in_mb "*" $system_cpu_cores)`
    max_sensible_yg_in_mb="400"

    desired_yg_in_mb=`expr $max_heap_size_in_mb / 4`
    if [ "$desired_yg_in_mb" -gt "$max_sensible_yg_in_mb" ]
    then
        HEAP_NEWSIZE="${max_sensible_yg_in_mb}M"
    else
        HEAP_NEWSIZE="${desired_yg_in_mb}M"
    fi

echo "Max heap size = " $MAX_HEAP_SIZE
echo " New gen size = " $HEAP_NEWSIZE
```

Putting this in a script file (machineInfo.sh) and running it on my DEV server yields this output:

```
$ ./machineInfo

This is how Cassandra will determine its default Heap and GC
Generation sizes.    
memory = 3948
half = 1974   
quarter = 987
cpu cores = 4
Max heap size =  1024M
New gen size =  256M
```

In summary, your error message seems to point to a setting (`memtable_total_space_in_mb`) which is about 1/25th of what it should be.  And that setting is (usually) based on the size of the JVM heap which is 3.5 times greater than it should be.  I'll also go ahead and agree that Cassandra 2.0.8 has substantial improvements over 1.1.7, and it would be worth your while to upgrade.

That being said, try altering the settings that I have mentioned, and restart your cluster.  Compared to running an upgrade, that's a quicker task with a lower degree of risk.

Comment: Hi Bryce, Thank you for your suggest. I have tried  it.Max heap size =12G, HEAP_NEWSIZE = 3G and memtable_total_space_in_mb= 4096. Cassandra server shows below error:

Comment: WARN 15:16:55,257 Heap is 0.7549211790158955 full.  You may need to reduce memtable and/or cache sizes.  Cassandra will now flush up to the two largest memtables to free up memory.  Adjust flush_largest_memtables_at threshold in cassandra.yaml if you don't want Cassandra to do this automatically

Comment: WARN 15:16:55,257 Flushing CFS(Keyspace='system', ColumnFamily='Versions') to relieve memory pressure
 INFO 15:16:55,257 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-Versions@217811680(83/103 serialized/live bytes, 3 ops)
 INFO 15:16:55,258 Writing Memtable-Versions@217811680(83/103 serialized/live bytes, 3 ops)
 INFO 15:16:55,740 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/Versions/system-Versions-hf-165-Data.db (247 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1404466149969, position=544)

Comment: If any other changes need in yaml file? like : #concurrent_compactors: 1; commitlog_total_space_in_mb: 4096;

Comment: Or need to change in flush_largest_memtables_at: 0.75 size.. I am badly worry with this.

Comment: Check the doc on the cassandra.yaml.  Under the section for "memtable settings" you'll see that you can increase the number of memtable_flush_writers, which is useful "If you have a large Java heap size and many data directories, you can increase the value for better flush performance.": http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__PerformanceTuningProps

Comment: Thanks Bryce, But I am unable to find the exact issues, Else any other way to compress and store the data in to DB, or Any smart queries to retrieve the data with short usage of memory?

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra, prior to 2.0, was unable to page through results, so your entire query has to fit in server memory. I would highly recommended upgrading to Cassandra 2.0, and use the CQL query engine's iteration in order to perform large queries.

If you are unable to do that, then you will need to retrieve your data in smaller chunks.

Your heap is too big, but that is not causing this particular problem.

Comment: While I do agree that the OP should be on 2.0, I really don't think an upgrade alone is going to resolve the error.

Comment: Have you tried using cql iteration over large results in 2.0?

Comment: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/client-side-improvements-in-cassandra-2-0 (Automatic Paging section)

Comment: Yes, I have used CQL to iterate over large result sets in C*2.0.  I have also read that article before, and you are correct about 2.0's ability to handle large data sets.  But upgrading won't change the fact that his heap is set way too high (his cluster is probably unusable during GC), and his memtable size (the setting that his error calls out) is probably grinding the server to a halt because it'll often be busy flushing to disk when it gets any real traffic.